# Optimizing MySQL query that does 3 counts and group by

Tags: php, mysql

Hey there to everyone,

What I am struggling with is the following and I would highly appreciate some suggestions on how I can improve the performance of this query

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(*) AS `pageviews`, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT `sessions_events`.`session_id`) AS `sessions`, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT `sessions_events`.`visitor_id`) AS `visitors`,
   `sessions_events`.`date_day` 
FROM 
   `sessions_events`
LEFT JOIN
   `websites_visitors` ON `sessions_events`.`visitor_id` = `websites_visitors`.`visitor_id`
WHERE 
    `sessions_events`.`website_id` = 1
    AND (`sessions_events`.`date_day` BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-31')
GROUP BY
    `sessions_events`.`date_day`
```

And the current state of the Table that I am trying to fetch from is looking like this:

[image: Table]

I was initially **DATE_FORMAT(`sessions_events`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `formatted_date`** and grouping by **`formatted_date`** but I have also created another **date_day** that only stores the actual date ( without H:I:S ) and to get rid of the usage of **DATE_FORMAT()**.

This table (sessions_events) is filled now with **5 million rows** across 5 different websites ( about 1 million per website_id ) as I have wanted to test out the performance.

For the above query to complete it takes about **13-15 seconds**.

If you are asking about the LEFT JOIN: I am using that in case someone in the frontend wants to apply filters to the selection and only check pageviews, sessions and visitors that have been accessed from United States (for example).

Here is what I need the data to look like:

[image: db query result]

This data is used for generating a chart that shows the pageviews, sessions and visitors on from a specific date range.

Any help on this would be appreciated as I just can't see how I could improve on this..

Thank you again!

Comment: This is good. I think the best you can hope for is a composite index on some arrangement of (visitor_id,website_id,date)

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Strawberry ! Tried this but no real change in the performance unfortunately. In your opinion this performance is the most you could get?

Comment: Have you tried `Explain` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html  to find possible bottlenecks?

Comment: @BrainFooLong Yes -> https://i.imgur.com/hlqR9kb.png but I personally couldn't find anything extra from this explain..

Comment: According to the EXPLAIN, it is examining 2.1 million rows, even after the index optimizes the search. That is going to take a while no matter what. Maybe the only remaining solutions are (a) get a faster server and allocate more RAM to the InnoDB buffer pool, or (b) use summary tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is create a composite index containing the fields `website_id` and `date_day`. That should speed up the query for you.

```
ALTER TABLE `sessions_events`
  ADD INDEX `website_id_date_day` (`website_id` ASC, `date_day` ASC);
```

## EDIT

After the chat, a fix was found by adding two indexes instead of the above one, and rewriting the query:

```
ALTER TABLE `sessions_events`
  ADD INDEX `website_id_date_day_session_id` (`website_id` ASC, `date_day` ASC, `session_id` ASC);

ALTER TABLE `sessions_events`
  ADD INDEX `website_id_date_day_visitor_id` (`website_id` ASC, `date_day` ASC, `visitor_id` ASC);


SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS `pageviews`,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT(`tmp`.`session_id`))
    FROM
      `sessions_events` AS `tmp`
    WHERE
      `sessions_events`.`website_id` = `tmp`.`website_id`
      AND `sessions_events`.`date_day` = `tmp`.`date_day`
  ) AS `sessions`,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT(`tmp`.`visitor_id`))
    FROM
      `sessions_events` AS `tmp`
    WHERE
      `sessions_events`.`website_id` = `tmp`.`website_id`
      AND `sessions_events`.`date_day` = `tmp`.`date_day`
  ) AS `visitors`,
  `sessions_events`.`date_day`
FROM
  `sessions_events`
WHERE
  `sessions_events`.`website_id` = 1
  AND (`sessions_events`.`date_day` BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-31')
GROUP BY
  `sessions_events`.`date_day`
```

This makes the query use subqueries, that in their turn can make use of the added indexes.

Comment: Thank you for the comment,

I have tried this already as suggested by another comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59562653/optimizing-mysql-query-that-does-3-counts-and-group-by#comment105293522_59562653

But unfortunately I can't see any performance improvements as the query still takes 13-15s to execute.

In this particular query, the LEFT JOIN can be indeed removed but it is there as other  filters can be applied that are linked to the 'websites_visitors' table.

Comment: I missed that comment. And I don't see the composite index in your screenshot of the table indexes. Are you sure it's there?

Comment: No worries ^_^ I have added the composite index after the comment from the other person as I have not tested it initially, this is why it is not in the initial screenshot.

Comment: I think @Strawberry 's suggestion to include visitor_id in the composite index is not necessary and may render the index useless for your query. Try it again, leaving out the visitor_id, the way I wrote it in my answer.

Comment: Just did and for some reason the performance is slower. Should I remove any of the previous indexes after adding your suggested composite index? https://i.imgur.com/q2XbgGj.png

Comment: MySql usually picks the most appropriate index it can find. So you don't need to remove previous indexes. Can you please share the output of `show create table sessions_events` in the question, so we can see the index you created?

Comment: Also you might want to prepend the word "DESCIBE" or "EXPLAIN" to your query and share that result as well.

Comment: Here are both the things you have requested: https://imgur.com/a/hYt0ZgP thank you deeply for trying to help ^_^

Comment: Everything looks the way it should be now. The query should actually be really fast given the numbers you have showed. Maybe your my.ini / my.cnf is set to tightly, making it have to create temporary tables or something?

Comment: I haven't changed the my.ini / my.cnf files at all, I am doing the tests on a $5 DO server with all the default settings. I am not running on production but I wanted to see if its possible to get more performance out of this

Comment: Another thing you can try is doing `optimize table sessions_events` once and wait for it to complete.

Comment: This is what resulted after the query: https://i.imgur.com/j8VNWW4.png

Comment: One last thing: I just noticed your date field is nullable ("Allow null"). Can you make it non-nullable and then try again?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no noticeable performance gain, tried everything you said and suggested. Not sure what to do next

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205234/discussion-between-nl-x-and-fabian).

Answer (score -2):

Hey fabian I am not sure but check by creating view you can check performance
by running:

```
select * from get_chart
```

Code:

```
create view get_chart
as
    "query or table where you set all data"
```

As an example

```
CREATE VIEW [Brazil Customers] 
AS
    SELECT CustomerName, ContactName
    FROM Customers
    WHERE Country = "Brazil";
```

Comment: Adding another layer of complexity on top of an inefficient query won't improve its performance.

Comment: naval might not know that MySQL views are not materialized views. A view just runs the SELECT query in the view definition, every time. It's more like a macro.

Comment: Thanks bill thats why i say in my answer that i am not sure